# How to grep files under a pattern path

Tags: unix, grep

Let's say there is the following tree of directories:

```
foo/
   +bar/
   |   +VIEW/
   |   |    +other/
   |   |          +file.groovy
   |   |    +file2.groovy
   |   |    +file.txt
   |   +file3.groovy
   +xyz/
       +VIEW/
            +file4.groovy
       +file5.groovy
```

And I want to grep `method` only on groovy files that are into any directory that either is **VIEW** or is under **VIEW** (that would be file.groovy, file2.groovy and file4.groovy).

I'm trying to do so using `--include=.*\/VIEW\/.*\.groovy` which as far as I know is the regex for *anything and then / character and then the word VIEW and then / character and then anything and then the word .groovy*

But that actually doesn't return anything.

Isn't there a way of doing this using the `include` option?

Comment: For `grep` in `POSIX` (i.e. most certified `UNIX` systems) there is no such option `--include`, be aware of `UNIX`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying the `-path` option for `find` should work:

```
find foo/ -path "*/VIEW/*" -name "*.groovy" -exec grep method {} \;
```

Answer (score 6):

From the [UNIX philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy):

> Write programs that do one thing and do it well.
>   Write programs to work together.

I don't like the GNU extension for recursive directory searching. The tool `find` does a much better job, has a cleaner syntax with more options and doesn't break the philosophy!

```
$ find foo/*/VIEW -name "*.groovy" -exec grep method {} \;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that actually not find file4.groovy? Either way I'll try this approach. But I read that grep was faster than find -exec and the actual directory tree is way bigger.

Comment: @Alfergon correct, easy fix, updated to use globbing. I have always thought `grep` was slow at this and `find` was much faster?

Comment: I tried this and it tells me that the directory doesn't exist (I'm actually trying ./*/VIEW)

Comment: I'm using cygwin, may it be the problem why it isn't working?

Comment: I don't it should be problem with `cygwin` are you sure `VIEW` exists 2 levels down from the current working directory.

Comment: VIEW directories are actually under projectn/src/main/java/VIEW

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to provide directory path in `include=` option, just provide the path as last argument to recursive grep.

Thus you can simply do:

```
grep -R 'method' --include=*.groovy foo/bar/VIEW/
```

Comment: How that will find `*.groovy` in `foo/xyz/VIEW` dir?

Comment: Yes it will find `*.groovy` in `foo/xyz/VIEW`

Comment: Don't know what do you mean by `(it doesn't recurse well` it worked for me and found all the files recursively.